# SQL LOADER same value in multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-loader

I have the data in the following format

```
Customer_ID, Party_ID, First_Name, Last_Name
```

I want to insert the data in two table in the following way using SQL LOADER

```
Customer Table:
Customer_ID, First Name

Party Table:
Customer_ID, Party_ID, First_Name, Last_Name
```

The Customer_ID in both the table are to use Customer_Seq.nextVal

How can I insert into these two tables, so that both the tables should get the same Customer_Seq sequence ID and First Name

Comment: I would load the data into a staging table and then do the data manipulations in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have correct Customer_ID in your data file and you know, for sure, that they can be safely insert.

You can disable your trigger(s) on Customer_ID before loading data:

```
ALTER TRIGGER MY_TRG_NAME DISABLE;
```

and to put it back after:

```
ALTER TRIGGER MY_TRG_NAME ENABLE;
```

But remember to **be careful with what you insert !**